# How do I change the consensus algorithm for a network that i forked from github?

Tags: consensus

can i change the consensus algorithm for a network that has forked from github? is there any link to understand how can make changes to consensus

Comment: Can you clarify which client you're using? Geth? Parity? A different one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have forked then you are free to change the consensus code.

The consensus part is mostly in the [`consensus/`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/consensus) directory of the https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum repository.

I don't know of any guide to make modifications to geth source. Since the code is always changing it is likely that such guide will be obsolete almost immediately.